# Nunit difference between `Assert.AreEqual` and `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` for IEnumerables

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, ienumerable

In Nunit, is there any difference between

```
Assert.AreEqual(IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>)
```

and

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>)
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no overload `Assert.AreEqual(IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>)`, only `Assert.AreEqual(object, object)`.  And at least for `nunit` 2.5.10 their implementation are the same:

### CollectionAssert.cs

```
public class CollectionAssert
{
    public static void AreEqual(IEnumerable expected, IEnumerable actual)
    {
      Assert.That((object) actual, (IResolveConstraint) new EqualConstraint((object) expected));
    }
}
```

### Assert.cs

```
public class Assert
{
    public static void AreEqual(object expected, object actual)
    {
      // EqualConstraint EqualTo(object expected)
      Assert.That(actual, (IResolveConstraint) Is.EqualTo(expected), (string) null, (object[]) null);
    }
}
```